# how to write single page subfile in cobol

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

I was able to do lots of COBOL programs using subfile, but lately I needed a keyword to indicate the page down, page up buttons while traversing the subfile. 
I managed to catch the keyword indicator only when <kbd>page up</kbd> is pressed and it's the first page of subfile, and when <kbd>page down</kbd> is pressed and it's the last page of subfile, but I couldn't catch the <kbd>page down</kbd> and <kbd>page up</kbd> otherwise, so I looked it up and found that single page subfile might be the only way to indicate the rolling buttons. 
I found [this example](http://www.go4as400.com/Single-page-subfile-example-RPGLE/SFL-4.aspx?cid=44) but I couldn't figure out what kind of coding they are using.

What I want is a way to do it using IBM COBOL/400.

Comment: Did I understood you correctly that you *don't* want to use "subfile" but a COBOL program to read the file and handle the keyboard, correct?

Comment: `...what kind of coding...` Can you clarify? Are you saying that you don't know the programming language? It's RPG IV, older fixed-format source lines using even older statement syntax.

Comment: BTW, do you really want COBOL/400 rather than ILE COBOL?

Comment: @SimonSobisch No, I want either COBOL/400 or ILE COBOL to load subfile page by page.

Comment: @user2338816 Yeah I meant I don't know the syntax. And no I'd rather use ILE COBOL instead of COBOL/400 since it has more features.

Comment: Have you looked at the IBM ILE COBOL documentation? The Knowledge Center has an example of a page-at-a-time subfile and an ILE COBOL program that processes it in the [**Using Transaction Files**](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzase/transac.htm) section of the Programmer's Guide.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand what you want to do.  But perhaps the following will allow you edit your question to make it more clear.

First thing, you need to understand what the `SFLSIZ` and `SFLPAG` keywords mean.

`SFLPAG` --> Number of subfile records on screen at once
`SFLSIZ` --> Number of record in the subfile

These two keywords are related and can be used in the following ways
**Page at a time subfile**-->*`SFLPAG = SFLSIZ`*: Your application must handle both <kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> and <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> key presses.  Your application loads one screens worth of records at a time.  This technique is useful when there are more than 9999 records that may possibly be displayed.

**Load all subfile**-->*`SFLPAG <> SFLSIZ`*: Your application loads all records to the subfile.  The system handles <kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> and <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> key presses.  You can only load a maximum of 9999 records into a subfile.

**Extending subfile**-->*`SFLPAG <> SFLSIZ`*: Your application loads one screen of records at a time.  Your application only needs to handle <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> key press.  The system will handle the <kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> key press.

Used to be, Load all subfiles were only used when you had very few records.  Since the entire buffer (ie. `SFLSIZ`) is sent to the display device.  When dealing with 2400 baud comm lines, you didn't want to send anything you didn't have to.

Extending subfiles were a compromise, a bit less work for your app and you only sent the data if it was needed.

Now-a-days, given the speed of the comm links, you can just use a load all subfile unless you have more than 9999 records to display.  Nice benefit, is that if you happen to start using some sort of web-facing tool, the tool can for instance allow the UI to sort/filter by column on the client side since it has all the data available.

If you have more than 9999 records, you're stuck with a page at a time subfile if you really want the use to be able to page through 10,000+ records.
Personally, I'd consider displaying a message telling the user than there's more than 10,000 records and provide a way to select/filter the records down to a more reasonable number that would fit in a load all subfile.

The thing to keep in mind is that the 5250 protocol isn't a "dumb terminal".  Every key press you make isn't sent instantly to the host. When I say the system handles <kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> or <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd>, what I really mean is that the client terminal (emulator) handles it.  Control is returned to your app only when needed.  If you use for instance, the `VALUES` keyword on a field, that validation is handled on the terminal side, not the server.